# Setting array items from a custom created class

Tags: c#, arrays, coordinates, xamarin, element

In Xamarin I have the following class that I have created:

```
class MapLocation
{
    public LatLng Location;
    public BitmapDescriptor icon;
    public String Snippet;
    public String Title;
}
```

I am trying to add MapLocation elements to this array as follows:

```
private MapLocation[] MapLocations = new MapLocation[1];
MapLocations[0].Location = new LatLng(-45.227660, 174.212731);
MapLocations[0].Title = 'Test Title';

MapLocations[1].Location = new LatLng(-45.227834, 174.212857);
MapLocations[1].Title = 'Test Title';
```

I am normally a Visual Basic programmer, and I am not sure as to what is wrong with the above code.

May I have some help to get this code working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exact issue, what error do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# `new` takes as parameter size (length) of array, not the last index (which is length-1). So just change it to

```
new MapLocation[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, the only wrong I see is that you have defined an array of one item new MapLocation[1], and you're accessing two items (0 and 1)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into above code it seems that you have created array with length = 1. and you are adding two elements into it. This might be the case which causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the initialization statement like this :

```
private MapLocation[] MapLocations = new MapLocation[2];
```